# How to choose between constructor / parameter injection?

Tags: dependency-injection

My question is a bit vague ...

Let's say I have this process for sending a mail to a Shop when there is a new order

```
class BookingMessager : IBookingMessager{
  BookingMessager(IBookingDataSource source,IBookingMessageFactory messageFactory,IMessager messager){
    this.source = source;
    this.messageFactory= messageFactory;
    this.messager = messager;
  }
  void SendBookingMessage(int idBooking){
    Booking aBooking = source.GetById(idBooking);
    BookingMessage aMessage = messageFactory.Create(aBooking);
    messager.SendMessage(aBooking.Shop.Contact,aMessage.Title,aMessage.Content);
  }
}
```

This is working well.

New requirement : I have to change my message body depending on the Shop.

I though about these solutions : I create a IBookingMessageFactory that'll call the required IBookingMessageFactory  depending on the shop like that

```
BookingMessage Create(Booking aBooking){
return this.BookingMessageFactoryIndex.ContainsKey(aBooking.Shop.ID) ? this.BookingMessageFactoryIndex[aBooking.Shop.ID].Create(aBooking) : this.default.Create(aBooking);
}
```

Or I inject the IBookingMessageFactory as a parameter, but that'll force me to update my interface IBookingMessager :(

What is the best solution ? Is my first code OK ? How do I choose between constructor and parameter injection ?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer you can't do that, please !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting the `IBookingMessageFactory` return a shop-specific `BookingMessage` looks fine by me. It seems you are using a composite/decorator `IBookingMessageFactory` that will delegate to a shop-specific implementation, which is great, since this keeps things simple.

Comment: yes but with this solution, I'll end up with some kind of lasagana code no ?

Comment: Lasagna has layers, so that is good. Spagette is bad :-). What is the problem?

Comment: If you mean that using decorators is lagasgna (layered), than you're right. It raises the abstraction, but my experience is that this debugs fine. It's a bit harder to jump (F12, assuming you use .NET and Visual Studio) from class to class, since it is at less clear at coding time which classes are used, but during debugging this will get clear. On the up side, this adds a lot of flexibility to the application and allows you to add features without changing code ([Open/closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)).

Comment: You're right, thanks ! The problem with SOLID, is that you're always filling like either you've too many layers or not enough.

Comment: @Remi: The saying is that there is not a problem in software that can't be solved by adding another layer of abstraction, of course the problem of having too many layers of abstraction :-)